# ¿Como multiplicar un numero entero por hora, minutos y segundos con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Necesito realizar una operacion matematica la cual consiste en calcular el tiempo total de mecanizado.**

Este tiempo total **se obtiene del resultado de multiplicar la cantidad de piezas a fabricar (numero entero) por el tiempo que me demora en fabricar una pieza (tiempo con formato de hh:mm:ss)**, 
y este resultado se debe obtener, convertir al formato de hora, minutos y segundos.

Dentro de mi formulario tengo los siguientes campos:

[image: tiempo de mecanizado]

Este es mi html:

```
  <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Tiempo de mecanizado</h3>                
            </div>            
            <div class="box-body">                 
                <div class="form-group">          
                    {!! Form::label('amount', 'Cantidad Mecanizada:') !!} 
                    {!! Form::text('amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'amount', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese la cantidad de piezas
                     fabricadas']) !!}                       
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">          
                    {!! Form::label('time', 'Tiempo de mecanizado:') !!} 
                    {!! Form::text('time', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'time', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el tiempo de mecanizado']) !!}                       
                </div>
                <p class="resultado">Resultado: <span id="resultado">0</span></p>
                <button id="calcular">Calcular tiempo de mecanizado</button>
             </div>  
        </div>
```

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente script: con este script obviamente se están multiplicando números enteros, **el punto es el siguiente: mi segunda variable ( var segundoValor = $('#time').val() ), tiene que aceptar el formato que le estoy pasando a traves de mi input $('#time') multiplicar y obtener el resultado en el formato hora, minutos y segundos**, aclarado esto ¿De que manera puedo realizar este calculo? ¿Como puedo obtener este resultado en el formato hora?

```
<script>

     $('#time').timepicker({
           showInputs: false,                   
           minuteStep: 1,       
           secondStep: 1,         
           showSeconds: true,
           showMeridian: false,
           defaultTime: false                    
     });


    $(function() {
        //Operación matemática
      $('#calcular').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Almaceno los valores de los inputs
        var primerValor = $('#amount').val();
        var segundoValor = $('#time').val()

        //Condiciona para que acepte solo números usando las expresiones regulares
        if(primerValor.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && segundoValor.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){

            var resultado = parseFloat(primerValor) * parseFloat(segundoValor);

        }else{
            alert("Ingrese números en los campos");
        }
        //Muestro el resultado
        $('#resultado').text(resultado);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres obtener el tiempo total multiplicando el tiempo con la cantidad de piezas verdad? Si es así lo primero que tienes que hacer es convertir el tiempo `hh:mm:ss` a una sola unidad, en este caso a segundos. Después multiplicar el tiempo por el número de piezas para finalmente volver a convertir a formato de hora `hh:mm:ss`.

Basicamente en tu código debería ir como:

```
$(function() {
        //Operación matemática
      $('#calcular').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Almaceno los valores de los inputs
        var primerValor = $('#amount').val();
        var segundoValor = $('#time').val()



        let arrayTime = segundoValor.split(":").reverse();
        let timeSeconds = isNaN(arrayTime[0]) ? 0 : parseInt(arrayTime[0]);
            timeSeconds += isNaN(arrayTime[1]) ? 0 : parseInt(arrayTime[1]) * 60;
            timeSeconds += isNaN(arrayTime[2]) ? 0 : parseInt(arrayTime[2]) * 60 * 60;
        let totalAmount = isNaN(primerValor) ? 0 : parseInt(primerValor);

        let totalTime = totalAmount * timeSeconds;

        let hours = Math.floor(totalTime / 3600);
        let minutes = Math.floor(totalTime % 3600 / 60);
        let seconds = totalTime % 60;

        hours = hours.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        minutes = minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        seconds = seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0");

        let resultado = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;


        //Muestro el resultado
        $('#resultado').text(resultado);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Saludos @Vlady, gracias por responder, si es exactamente lo que pretendo, solo tengo una duda, no comprendo modifico mi script original?

Comment: No comprendi la respuesta anterior, alguien mas me podria orientar, como relaciono la respuesta en mi script?

Comment: Debes adaptarlo a tu código, lo puse así como función para poder ejecutarlo y saber si es lo que realmente querías o no, en vez de ir adivinando.

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta adaptándolo a tu código.

Comment: Estuve revisando  tu respuesta, el funcionamiento es el esperado, me estaria faltando algo de validacion el ambos campos como verificar si realmente se ha ingresado una cantidad y un tiempo, igualmente muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio tu respuesta.